# Is it possible to get system(@args) to preserve shell metacharacters?

Tags: perl, system

Consider the following command involving a pipe:

```
$ echo Hi | tee test.log
Hi
```

---

Based on [`perldoc exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html):

> If there is more than one argument in `LIST`, or if `LIST` is an array
>   with more than one value, calls `execvp(3)` with the arguments in `LIST`.
>   **If there is only one scalar argument or an array with one element in
>   it, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are
>   any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for
>   parsing** (this is `/bin/sh -c` on Unix platforms, but varies on other
>   platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it
>   is split into words and passed directly to `execvp` , which is more
>   efficient.

---

Based on this, the following command does not tee output:

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wle 'my @args = ( "Hi", "| tee test.log" );
                      system( "echo", @args );'
Hi | tee test.log
```

Whereas this one does:

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wle 'my @args = ( "Hi", "| tee test.log" );
                      system( join " " => "echo", @args );'
Hi
```

The question is not so much about how to `tee` as it is about how to pipe within a system command (else [`File::Tee`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aTee) would suffice as an alternative).

I feel it could be useful to be able to provide multiple pipes in `@args` form without having to resort to command stringification.

Comment: No, you can't do it with `system()` that way. When you call it with multiple arguments, there's no shell involved.

Comment: @Barmar : If it's not possible with `system`, is there an alternative interface via a CPAN module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to mix the list form of `system()` with redirection, pipes etc., then use the CPAN module `IPC::Run`:

```
use IPC::Run 'run';
run ["echo", "Hi"], "|", ["tee", "rso.log"] or die;
```